# Pyspark from_json function equvalent

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, fromjson

I have `dataframe` with column containing json string, which is converted to dictionary using `from_json` function. Problem occured when json contains not typical string inside like: `'\\"cde\\"'`, all json: `'{"key":"abc","value":"\\"cde\\""}'`.

When from_json function is applied, it returns `null` because I think it treats `\\` as one char and it can not parse `value` due to many `"` inside.

Here is simple code snippet:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, '{"key":"abc","value":"\\\\"cde\\\\""}')
    ],
    ["id", "text"]
)

df = df.withColumn('dictext', from_json(col('text'), json_schema))

display(df)
```

Is there way for cleaning such json or maybe encoding it somehow before calling`from_json` or using another function, which is able to parse such string?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there way for cleaning such json

For your case, I would suggest creating an UDF, that captures the cleaning rules that are relevant to your data. For the single line of data you have included, I created a sample UDF that removes all *incorrect* tokens and parses the JSON correctly:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("string")
def clean_json(json: str):
    return json.replace("\\", "").replace("\"\"", "\"")

# Applying the UDF
df = df.withColumn('dictext', from_json(clean_json(col('text')), json_schema))
display(df)
```

[image: display(df)]

#### Cleaning rows with regex

If you can capture all your *unwanted* characters with regular expression, then you don't need the UDF - you use your regex with `regexp_replace` function directly, like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df = df.withColumn('dictext', from_json(regexp_replace('text', r'\\', '')), json_schema))
```

Docs for [regexp_replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html#pyspark-sql-functions-regexp-replace)

Comment: With this solution I need each time to add cleaning rule if I receive other char e.g. "\+"

Comment: Hi gorrch, I've added an example of cleaning using regular expression - if you can build your regex to capture all applicable cases, then you don't need to any extra rules whenever something new pops in :)